# The best way to divide card-deck into rows in Django template - Django

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-templates

I want to show 6 items in a page with the same design, like this photo: `https://pasteboard.co/Jrkehgg.png`.

I have this code in a HTML page:

```
{% for android in single_android_post %}
   <div class="card-deck">

     <div class="card">
       <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ android.get_image }}" height="240px" width="230px" alt="اذا رأيت هذه الجمله فيرجى التواصل معنا واخبارنا بمكان الخطا لاصلاحه">
       <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title">{{ android.name }}</h5>
         <p class="card-text"> {{ android.app_contect}} </p>
       </div>
       <div class="card-footer">
         <small class="text-muted">{{ android.post_date}}</small>
         <small class="firstsmall"><a class="bg-orange" href="" title="">{{ android.post_tag}}</a></small>
       </div>
     </div>

</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried this code but each card takes up all of the page width. How do I fix it?

Comment: Does it work perfectly without django template?

Comment: yes if i add 3  <div class="card"> </div> inside  <div class="card-deck">

Comment: what about 4 ``<div class="card"> </div> inside <div class="card-deck">``. Does it still work or it has to be 3?

Comment: if i add 4 or 5 etc .. inside      <div class="card-deck">     it will show all of items like photo 
This is what I do not want to happen
i want show 3 items in row then show more 3 items at the bottom
Not next to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
<div class="card-deck">
{% for android in single_android_post %}
    <div class="card">
       <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ android.get_image }}" height="240px" width="230px" alt="اذا رأيت هذه الجمله فيرجى التواصل معنا واخبارنا بمكان الخطا لاصلاحه">
       <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title">{{ android.name }}</h5>
         <p class="card-text"> {{ android.app_contect}} </p>
       </div>
       <div class="card-footer">
         <small class="text-muted">{{ android.post_date}}</small>
         <small class="firstsmall"><a class="bg-orange" href="" title="">{{ android.post_tag}}</a></small>
       </div>
     </div>
    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
</div>
<div class="card-deck">
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

See: [forloopcounter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for) and [divisibleby](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby)

Comment: oh , thanks it's work perfect , thanks for your time